# How is this loop ending and are the results deterministic?

Tags: c, iteration

I found some code and I am baffled as to how the loop exits, and how it works. Does the program produce a deterministic output?

The reason I am baffled is:

```
1. `someArray` is of size 2, but clearly, the loop goes till size 3,
2. The value is deterministic and it always exits `someNumber` reaches 4
```

Can someone please explain how this is happening?

The code was not printing correctly when I put angle brackets `<>` around include's library names.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int someNumber = 97;
    int someArray[2] = {0,1};
    int findTheValue;

    for (findTheValue=0; (someNumber -= someArray[findTheValue]) >0; findTheValue++) {

    }
        printf("The crazy value is %d", findTheValue);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Really, I would have guessed findTheValue would = 0 as the output... Because, someNumber -= someArray[findTheValue] when findTheValue == 0 is definitely > 0...

Comment: @anon: the loop continues until the condition is false

Comment: It might work every time on your computer, but is is not deterministic. Just because it works when you run it doesn't mean the code is good.

Comment: This code reads memory past the end of the array. It's a bug and renders the output meaningless. You may get a consistent output on your machine but the code is still broken and useless.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array element beyond its bounds is undefined behavior. That is, the program is allowed to do anything it pleases, reply `42`, eat your hard disk or spend all your money. Said in other words what is happening in such cases is entirely platform dependent. It may look "deterministic" but this is just because you are lucky, and also probably because you are only reading from that place and not writing to it.

This kind of code is just bad. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler, `someArray[2]` is a pointer to `findTheValue`!

Because these variables are declared one-after-another, it's entirely possible that they would be positioned consecutively in memory (I believe on the stack).  C doesn't really do any memory management or errorchecking, so `someArray[2]` just means the memory at `someArray[0] + 2 * sizeof(int)`.

So when `findTheValue` is 0, we subtract, then when `findTheValue` is 1, we subtract 1.  When `findTheValue` is 2, we subtract `someNumber` (which is now 94) and exit.

**This behavior is by no means guaranteed**.  Don't rely on it!

EDIT: It is probably more likely that someArray[2] just points to garbage (unspecified) values in your RAM.  These values are likely more than 93 and will cause the loop to exit.

EDIT2: Or maybe `someArray[2]` and `someArray[3]` are large negative numbers, and subtracting both causes someNumber to roll over to negative.

Comment: I have ran this program many times on my computer and am consistently getting the same output... Are you sure? And it is his exact same output as well...

Comment: You may be right.  I edited my post.  Try printing the value of someArray[findTheValue] inside the loop and tell us what you see?

Comment: Here is the output i see consistently :-  findTheValue = 0 and someNumber = 97 and someArray[findTheValue] = 0
findTheValue = 1 and someNumber = 96 and someArray[findTheValue] = 1
findTheValue = 2 and someNumber = 94 and someArray[findTheValue] = 2The crazy value is 3

Comment: As i replied above , the first iteration in loop does 97-0, second iteration does 97-1, third iteration AND YES even though array size is 2, it has third iteration and it shows me 96-2, which is 94 and then the loop exits and shows crazyvalue to be 3.

Comment: But it maybe the same for you, but other compilers, other machines, can and almost certainly will give another value.  As it stands, your crazy value from code, should be the length of the array as a human would expect, however, as it shows, I compiled your code, and got a different result. It doesnt produce reliable answers.

Answer (score 1):

The loop exits because (someNumber -= someArray[findTheValue]) doesnt set.

Adding a debug line, you can see

```
value 0 number 97 array 0
value 1 number 96 array 1
value 2 number 1208148276 array -1208148180
```

that is printing out findTheValue, someNumber, someArray[findTheValue]

Its not the answer I would have expected at first glance.

Comment: Sorry, but i am simply not getting the output you displayed. I am using ubuntu 64 bit, gcc version 4.4.5

Comment: I replied to Brad's response with my output. As you can see, the value for someNumber -= someArray[findTheValue] is always set, and i can print that value after the for loop exits.

Comment: The problem, as someone else pointed out, is that the value that will be in the place array[2] is actually random, therefore you can and will get different results.

Comment: On what OS did you get the above answer and what compiler?

Comment: linux, gcc.  The problem as has been said is that the the 3rd element of the array can point to anything, if you repeatedly run it, chances are the same chunks of memory are potentially offered to the app and the same results occur, if you can run multiple copies simultaneously (and while its a quick app that makes it harder) you would see almost certainly entirely different results, as well as how the handling of the array is being done by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Checking addresses:

```
printf("&someNumber =   %p\n", &someNumber);
printf("&someArray[0] = %p\n", &someArray[0]);
printf("&someArray[1] = %p\n", &someArray[1]);
printf("&findTheValue = %p\n", &findTheValue);
```

gave this output:

```
&someNumber =   0xbfc78e5c
&someArray[0] = 0xbfc78e50
&someArray[1] = 0xbfc78e54
&findTheValue = 0xbfc78e58
```

It seems that for some reason the compiler puts the array in the beginning of the stack area, then the variables that are declared below and then those that are above in the order they are declared. So someArray[3] effectively points at someNumber.

I really do not know the reason, but I tried gcc on Ubuntu 32 bit and Visual Studio with and without optimisation and the results were always similar.